# $f\circ(g\circ g)=(g\circ g)\circ f$; $f\circ g\ne g\circ f$

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

Let $f\circ(g\circ g)=(g\circ g)\circ f$ but not equal for $f\circ g\ne g\circ f$. What are possible $f$ and $g$?

Answer (score 3):

$f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=-x$ seem to work.

Comment: Or $g(x)=-x$ and *any* $f$ which is not odd.

Answer (score 1):

Choose: $g(x) =1/x$;  or any $g$ with $g(g(x))= x = id(x).$

Now find  $f$ that does not commute with $g$.